# Ping/Post Form Handling with PHP?

Tags: post, ping

I'm working with a company on lead delivery, and they sent me some info regarding a Ping Post form setup. I've built hundreds of HTML forms processed by PHP (ie. sending an email/etc), but never something that would Ping a url, then return a value. The value it returns is XML.

Here's the purpose of the process:

1. I send a lead (form data) using the form with a particular zip code
2. This company parses that info, decides if it wants to "buy" it
3. Returns XML saying "Approved" or "Denied"
4. If "approved", I then post the data, and if "denied", I can do whatever I want

What is a common PHP method for doing this? I can research the code and put something together, just need to know what structure or PHP methods would work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking into RESTful Web Services.

here's a few examples that might help you

http://markroland.com/blog/restful-php-api/

http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

I did not create these examples, just what I found on Google.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at some of those articles, and it was easy enough to use file_get_contents() to get the data I needed. It's now responding with XML:

<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS><BR><VALIDATION MESSAGE>900- Duplicate Ping Request</VALIDATION MESSAGE>

Which I have in a string variable. Tried using simplexml_load_string but getting an error. Any idea the best way to parse that XML into workable variables?

Comment: An XML element had a space, so had to parse the string and added underscores for spaces in element names. Working now!

Answer (score 0):

I used file_get_contents(url) to handle the posting. The url contains inputs from the HTML form added as a query string, and the response is in XML which gets handled with simplexml_load_file().

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question what you need is to make an HTTP POST request and parse the incoming XML data.
I would rather not use file_get_contents() on remote servers - there are some potential security issues and it was missing some features the last time I checked. I strongly recommend [cURL](http://php.net/curl) for remote HTTP/HTTPS communication.

Depending on the API you are posting to you might be able to use the SOAPclient class, but from the look of the response you got all you need is [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) or [Simple XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Anyway if you just need to check if a certain keyword (like Approved or Denied) is present you can use a simple string matching like this

```
if(strpos($response,'<STATUS>APPROVED</STATUS')!==false){
  //approved
}
...
```